# Solve taking infinite time

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I have a system of equations that should determine the real coefficients `{b[1], c[1], d[1],, e[1], f[1], g[1], h[1], a[1], b[2], c[2], d[2], e[2], f[2], g[2], h[2]}`. Writing some of the equations inside `Solve` and compiling

```
Solve[{b[1]*e[1] + b[1] + e[1] + c[2]*f[2] - d[1]/2 - a[1]/2 == 0, 
  c[1]*f[1] + c[1] + f[1] + b[2]*e[2] - d[1]/2 - a[1]/2 == 0, 
  g[1]*d[1] + g[1] + d[1] - a[1] == 0, 
  a[1]*h[1] + h[1] - d[1] + a[1] == 0, 
  a[1]*d[2] + a[2]*d[1] + a[2] + d[2] + d[1]/2 - a[1]/2 == 0, 
  b[1]*e[2] + c[2]*f[1] + e[2] + c[2] + d[1]/2 - a[1]/2 == 0, 
  b[2]*e[1] + c[1]*f[2] + b[2] + f[2] + d[1]/2 - a[1]/2 == 0, 
  g[1]*h[1] + h[1] + g[1] == 0, 
  a[1]*d[1] + d[1] + a[1] + 4*a[2]*d[2] + 2*d[2] - 2*a[2] == 
     0}, {b[1], c[1], d[1], e[1], f[1], g[1], h[1],
   a[1], b[2], c[2], d[2], e[2], f[2], g[2], h[2]}]
```

it takes about 5-10s to run. However, if I add one more equation to the system

```
Solve[{b[1]*e[1] + b[1] + e[1] + c[2]*f[2] - d[1]/2 - a[1]/2 == 0, 
  c[1]*f[1] + c[1] + f[1] + b[2]*e[2] - d[1]/2 - a[1]/2 == 0, 
  g[1]*d[1] + g[1] + d[1] - a[1] == 0, 
  a[1]*h[1] + h[1] - d[1] + a[1] == 0, 
  a[1]*d[2] + a[2]*d[1] + a[2] + d[2] + d[1]/2 - a[1]/2 == 0, 
  b[1]*e[2] + c[2]*f[1] + e[2] + c[2] + d[1]/2 - a[1]/2 == 0, 
  b[2]*e[1] + c[1]*f[2] + b[2] + f[2] + d[1]/2 - a[1]/2 == 0, 
  g[1]*h[1] + h[1] + g[1] == 0, 
  a[1]*d[1] + d[1] + a[1] + 4*a[2]*d[2] + 2*d[2] - 2*a[2] == 0, 
  b[1]*f[1] + b[1] + f[1] + c[2]*e[2] + d[2] - a[2] == 0}, {b[1], 
  c[1], d[1], e[1], f[1], g[1], h[1], a[1], b[2], c[2], d[2], e[2], 
  f[2], g[2], h[2]}]
```

it takes infinite time, and I still need to add more equations to determine all coefficients, so that the method I am trying to use seems inappropriate.

Is there something I can do to accelerate the process?

Comment: may be because you have underdetermined systems (more variables than equations).  There is no unique solution in this case.  But I do not know exactly why it slows down when you added one more variable. It depends what algorithm Mathematica is using to solve undetermined system of equations.

Comment: `FindInstance` finishes very fast but only gives trivial solution.

Comment: @Nasser These equations should not determine all the variables, only after I add the remaining equations. However, they should still yield at least one solution where some of the variables are solved in terms of the others.

Comment: Including `a[2]` in the variables lists for `Solve` might provide more solutions but probably no faster.

Comment: I recommend that you post a new question with the complete set of equations you wish to solve.  Adding equations one at a time is not the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 6):

Solving large systems of polynomial equations can be very difficult.  The general approach involves using `GroebnerBasis`, which can be very slow.  Here is an approach for obtaining solutions to the system of ten equations in the question, given that obtaining the solution for the first nine of those equations is easy.  Designate the ten equations as `eq` and the corresponding variables as `var`.  Then

```
s9 = Solve[Most@eq, var] // Simplify;  
Length[s9]
(* 25 *)
```

is the result from the nine-equation system, which consists of 25 solutions.  With a `LeafCount` of 2938, `s9` is too long to display here.  (The computation required abut 20 seconds on my 5.3 GHz PC.)  Adding the tenth equation given in the question can be viewed as putting a constraint on those 25 solutions, which can be computed as follows:

```
Subtract @@@ Simplify[(Last@eq) //. # & /@ s9];
c10 = Simplify[Factor[Numerator[Together[#]]] & /@ %]
```

Here too, the result is much too long to be displayed.  So, consider a particularly simple component,

```
s9[[25]]
(* {b[1] -> -1, c[1] -> -1, d[1] -> -2 (1 + a[2]), e[1] -> -1, f[1] -> -1, 
    g[1] -> 0, h[1] -> 0, a[1] -> -2 (1 + a[2]), d[2] -> -a[2], 
    e[2] -> (-1 - 2 a[2])/b[2],f[2] -> (-1 - 2 a[2])/c[2]} *)

c10[[25]]
(* (1 + 2 a[2]) (b[2] + c[2]) *)
```

Combine them to obtain

```
Solve[Join[Equal @@@ s9[[25]], {c10[[25]] == 0}]]
(* {{a[1] -> -1, a[2] -> -(1/2), b[1] -> -1, c[1] -> -1, d[1] -> -1, d[2] -> 1/2, 
     e[1] -> -1, e[2] -> 0, f[1] -> -1, f[2] -> 0, g[1] -> 0, h[1] -> 0}, 
    {a[1] -> -2 (1 + a[2]), b[1] -> -1, b[2] -> -c[2], c[1] -> -1, 
     d[1] -> -2 (1 + a[2]), d[2] -> -a[2], e[1] -> -1, e[2] -> (1 + 2 a[2])/c[2], 
     f[1] -> -1, f[2] -> (-1 - 2 a[2])/c[2], g[1] -> 0, h[1] -> 0}} *)
```

which can be verified by substitution into the ten equations.

```
(And @@ Simplify[eq /. #] &) /@ %
(* {True, True} *)
```

This process can be applied to all 25 components of `s9` and `c10`, although the computation takes a bit over an hour.

```
s10 = Union[Simplify[Flatten[Parallelize[
    MapThread[Solve[Join[Equal @@@ #1, {#2 == 0}]] &, {s9, c10}], 
    Method -> "FinestGrained"], 1]]]
Length[%]
(* 67 *)
```

All 65 solutions can be verified by substitution into `eq`.

```
And @@ ((And @@ Simplify[eq /. #] &) /@ s10)
(* True *)
```

Whether this approach is generalizable to the still larger but unspecified equation set mentioned by the OP cannot be determined without seeing that set.

Comment: bbgodfrey I need your help please for a numerical solution with FinRoot

Comment: @Gallagher Please tell me the question number on Mathematica where you need help.

Comment: bbgodfrey thank you, this is the question. Please I need your email address for another problem 
  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/298297/58233

Comment: @Gallagher Please post your new question on Mathematic StackExchange and send me the question number..