# Solving numerical equation with FindRoot with high precision

Tags: equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

I try to solve numerically an algebraic equation wich contains Dawson's function. Solutions ***x*** of this equation depend on the two parameters ***a*** and ***b***. Then I try to plot ***x*** versus ***a*** for a given ***b***. Here is my code

```
$Version
(*"14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"*)

(************** Equation to solve *************)

func[k_?NumericQ]:= - 2 DawsonF[k] + I Sqrt[\[Pi]] Exp[-k^2]

eq[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ]:= a^2 + x - (x/(a Sqrt[b])) func[(x - 1)/(a Sqrt[b])]


(************** Solutions of eq *************) 

sol[a_,b_] := Flatten[Values /@ (FindRoot[eq[x, a, b] == 0, {x, 1/2 (-a^2 + Sqrt[a^4 + 4 a^2])},
                 AccuracyGoal -> 5,MaxIterations -> 1000])]//Quiet


(************** Solutions to plot *************)

avalues = Range[0.001, 3.001, 0.001];

(* Sol for b=0.001 *)
sol0001 = Block[{b = 0.001},Transpose@Table[Thread[{a, sol[a, b]}], {a, avalues}]]//Quiet;

(* sol for b=0.1 *)
sol01 =Block[{b = 0.1},Transpose@Table[Thread[{a, sol[a, b]}], {a, avalues}]] // Quiet;

(* sol for b=0.6 *)
sol06 = Block[{b = 0.6},Transpose@Table[Thread[{a, sol[a, b]}], {a, avalues}]] //Quiet;

(* sol for b=1 *)
sol1 = Block[{b = 1},Transpose@Table[Thread[{a, sol[a, b]}], {a, avalues}]] // Quiet;

(* sol for b=2 *)
sol2 = Block[{b = 2},Transpose@Table[Thread[{a, sol[a, b]}], {a, avalues}]] // Quiet;
```

My problem is about precision and accuracy for large ***a***. As you see below the plots for a given ***b*** is not continuous and intersects at a given ***a***.

```
(************** Plots *************)

ListLinePlot[{Re@sol0001[[1]], Re@sol01[[1]], Re@sol06[[1]], Re@sol1[[1]], Re@sol2[[1]]}, PlotRange -> {{0., 3}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True,GridLines -> Automatic, Joined -> True, FrameLabel -> {Text[Style["a", 12]], Text[Style["x", 12]]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Please, I would like to plot all solutions without cuts until ***a=15***. Thank you.

Comment: `Table[ContourPlot[
  eq[x, a, b] == 0, {a, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 1}], {b, {0.001, 0.1, 0.6, 1, 
   2}}]` ?

Comment: We cannot execute your code without the data.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon how to import data?

Comment: Post it on a file sharing site and provide a link to it here.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon I edited the code, the  data are expressed by sol0001, sol01, sol06 ...., just compile them.

Comment: Have you tried using a higher `WorkingPrecision`? For trickier numerical problems, machine precision often isn't good enough.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit even with higher `WorkingPrecision` it gives the same plots.

Answer (score 1):

`ContourPlot3D` shows the complete surface `Re[eq[x, a, b]]] == 0`

```
bi = {.001, .1, .6, 1, 2};
pic = ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[Re[eq[x, a, b]]] == 0, {a, 0 , 3}, {b, 0.001 , 2}, {x, 0 ,1}, AxesLabel -> {a, b, x}, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &) , Mesh -> {bi}]
```

[image]

plot confirms your result. Solution range of a is limited `0<a<f[b,x]<15`.

**addendum**

extract lines `b==const`

```
bi = {.001, .1, .6, 1, 2};
Show[Table[
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Re[eq[x, a, b]]] == 0, {a, 0 , 3.1} ,{x, 0 , 1},PlotPoints -> 50]
,{b, bi}], FrameLabel -> {a, x}, PlotLabel -> bi]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how to get the plots until `a=15` with high precision  without the cuts on my above plots?

Comment: @Gallagher These are the lines `b=const` in the `ContourPlot3D`

Comment: @Gallagher Have a look at my modified answer

Comment: thank you, but It goes up to `x=1`, it is not good at all.

Comment: In your question you assume `0<x<1` too!

Comment: not necessarily `0<x<1`, but it should go down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151553/discussion-between-gallagher-and-ulrich-neumann).

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Why we can't find the same solutions/plots by `FindRoot` ? Have you other suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

In my first answer, I assumed QP is looking for solutions `Re[eq[x,a,b]]==0`!

If this assumption is wrong and QP is looking for real solution `x,a,b` of the complex equation `eq[x,a,b]==0` than try

```
solaa[x_,b_] := (mini = 
NMinimize[ {# Conjugate[#] &[eq[x, a, b]], 0 < a < 15}, a  ]; {b,x, a /. mini[[2]], mini[[1]]}) // Quiet

bi = {.001, .1, .6, 1, 2}; (* values b *)
pts = Table[ solaa[x, b] , {b, bi}, {x, Subdivide[0.001, 1, 25]}]  ;
(*possible  solution points `x,a,b`*)

(* solution points `sol` must fullfill "pts[[i,-1]] small" *)
sol = Table[ Select[pts[[k]], Abs[#[[-1]]] < .0001 &], {k, 1, Length[pts]}]


Graphics[Line@Map[#[[All, {3, 2 }]] &, sol ], Axes -> True,AxesLabel -> {a, x}, PlotLabel -> bi]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, but why we can't plot solutions until a=15?

Comment: Probably because there are no solutions found. Try `Graphics[Line@Map[#[[All, {3, 2 }]] &, sol ], Axes -> True,AxesLabel -> {a, x}, PlotLabel -> bi,PlotRange->{{0,15},{0,1}}]`